# How to force first paragraph indentation in exam class

Tags: indentation, exam

I'm using the exam.cls and after `\question`, i have some description before going into `\part`.

How do i add an indent for the first line of the question?
I've tried `indentfirst` package, `\hspace{}`, `\itemindent`, `\parindent` and these didnt work.

[image]

```
\documentclass[addpoints, a4paper, 12pt]{exam}
\usepackage{setspace, amsmath, pdfpages, mathtools}
\usepackage{times}
\pagestyle{headandfoot}
\setstretch{1.3} 

\setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{2.5cm}
\cfoot[\thepage]{\thepage} % page numbering
\qformat  % Format for question
{
    \textbf{QUESTION \thequestion{} (\pointsofquestion{\thequestion} marks)} 
    \hfill
    \vrule depth 1.7em width 0pt
}

\pointsdroppedatright % enable points at the right margin
\marksnotpoints
\marginpointname{ \points}


% To adjust questions margins
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1em}
}

% To adjust parts margins
\renewcommand{\partshook}{%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.4cm}%
  \setlength{\labelsep}{1cm}
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{0cm}%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1em}

}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

\question
bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla 

\begin{parts}

    \part[5]
    bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla 
    
    \droppoints 
    
    \part[4]
    bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla 
    
    \droppoints 

\end{parts}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since the (empty) label is the first thing after \par (in \item), the code goes to great lengths to prevent paragraph indentation (including setting \parindent=0pt).   You could put the text into a \parbox and reset \parindent inside.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below I patch `\question` (defined within the environment `questions`) by appending an `\hspace*{1.5em}\ignorespaces` to it. That inserts the starting space.

[image]

```
\documentclass[addpoints, a4paper, 12pt]{exam}

\setlength{\rightpointsmargin}{2.5cm}
\cfoot[\thepage]{\thepage} % page numbering
\qformat  % Format for question
{%
    \textbf{QUESTION \thequestion{} (\pointsofquestion{\thequestion} marks)} 
    \hfill
    \vrule depth 1.7em width 0pt
}

\pointsdroppedatright % enable points at the right margin
\marksnotpoints
\marginpointname{ \points}


% To adjust questions margins
\renewcommand{\questionshook}{%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{0pt}%
    \setlength{\labelwidth}{-\labelsep}%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1em}%
  \let\oldquestion\question% Copy \question into \oldquestion
  \renewcommand{\question}{%
    \oldquestion% Default question style
    \hspace*{1.5em}\ignorespaces% Insert paragraph indent/space
  }%
}

% To adjust parts margins
\renewcommand{\partshook}{%
  \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.4cm}%
  \setlength{\labelsep}{1cm}
  \setlength{\labelwidth}{0cm}%
  \setlength{\itemsep}{1em}

}

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}

  \question
  bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla 

  \begin{parts}

    \part[5]
    bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla 
    
    \droppoints 
    
    \part[4]
    bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla bla bla bla bla blab bla 
    
    \droppoints 

  \end{parts}

\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

Comment: that works! and I learnt something new as well. thank you very very much.

Comment: @yungszen: If this answered your question, consider accepting it as such. See [How do you accept an answer?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1852/5764)